# How to get last month using Zend_Date()?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using below code to get last month:

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->setTimezone("UTC");
$date->sub('1', 'MM');
echo $date->get("yyyy-MM");
```

But, if it goes to `20150101` then will the `echo` result be `2014-12`, or `2015-00`? How to test my guess?

I've tested this with `new Zend_Date(array('year' => 2015, 'month' => 1, 'day' => 1))`, and it returns `2014-12`, so it has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternate way could be:

```
$nextYear = strtotime('2015-01-01');
$date = new Zend_Date($nextYear);
$date->setTimezone("UTC");
$date->sub('1', 'MM');
echo $date->get("yyyy-MM");
```